# Detect input audio level android

Tags: android

I'd appreciate any expert's help,

I'm trying to trigger an event when a user stops speaking.
My approach is to trace a single input audio volume-level integer and to measure it through time. 
I've looked into the aurioTouch and speakHere example.
The first utilize an FFT buffer which get parsed every time it is fills - i couldn't see how to determine the volume of the speech from it. The second doesn't do any sound analysis.

Do you know of a way?
Is there a mic-incoming-sound-level hidden var?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using `MediaRecorder`, you should be able to use the [getMaxAmplitude()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#getMaxAmplitude%28%29) method on a timed loop to see the "current" volume.